# unixtime ужать с 4 байт до 2

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

Можно ли ужать unixtime формата : 1506174280 с unt32 до uint16, убрав часы, минуты и секунды ?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66625/discussion-on-question-by-tomx01-unixtime---4---2).

Answer (score 3):

Если вас интересует точность до дней, то в uint16 войдет 65535/365 = 179 лет примерно. Это конечно уже будет не unix тайм, а просто количество лет.

Comment: Кол-во дней наверное

Comment: 179 лет * 365 дней в году = 65535. Нет, 179 лет все таки.

Comment: про последнее предложение "..будет не unix тайм, а просто количество лет."